# Different ways to fetch hidden value from JSP

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi i need to obtain one of the hidden values in my form to my Controller. How can i get it. Please find my code below . I need to get the value of hidden value in my controller`

```
@RequestMapping("/submitAdmissionForm.html",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitAdmissionForm(@RequestParam("studentName") String name, @RequestParam("studentHobby") String hobby) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionSuccess");
    model.addObject("msg","Details submitted by you:: Name: "+name+ ", Hobby: " + hobby);

    return model;
}
```

`

JSP pages

```html
<html>
<body>
 <h1> STUDENT ADMISSION FORM FOR ENGINEERING COURSES</h1>

 <form action="/submitAdmissionForm.html" method="post">
  <p>
   Student's Name : <input type="text" name="studentName" />
  </p>
  <p>
   Student's Hobby : <input type="text" name="studentHobby" />
  </p>
   <input type="hidden" id="Student" value="Sree" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit this form by clicking here" />
 </form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hidden inputs are like any other input. The same way you get `studentName` can be used to retrieve the value of `Sree`.

Comment: Just add name attribute in your input like : <input type="hidden" id="Student" name="Student" value="Sree" /> aftre that u can handle it with same way you applicated like another params

Answer (score 1):

Your hidden field does not have the `name` attribute, so it cannot be submitted.

You could do the following.

A. Replace this

```
<input type="hidden" id="Student" value="Sree" />
```

with

```
<input type="hidden" id="Student" name="Student" value="Sree" />
```

B. Add a new parameter to your controller method:

```
@RequestParam("Student") String hiddenStudent
```

It will contain the submitted value for that hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to add name attribute in your input and this is also same way but with Spring (cleaner):

```
//Send to form
@GetMapping("/StudentForm")
public String studentForm(Model model) {

   model.addAttribute("student", new Student());

    return "student-form";
}
```

---

**Jsp page :**

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="student" action="/submitAdmissionForm.html">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name: <form:input path="studentName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hobby: <form:input path="studentHobby" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>//for example there another student property but it will be hidden
            <td><form:hidden path="studentNickname" value="${Sree}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

---

**Spring Controller :**

```
@PostMapping("/submitAdmissionForm.html")
public String submitAdmissionForm(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student, Model model) {
      if(studen != null) {
           model.addObject("msg","Details submitted by you:: Name:"+student.getName()+ ", Hobby: " + student.getHobby() + "Nickname :" + student.getNickname());
      }
    return "success-form";
}
```